# Dynamic Select Boxes work half

Tags: php

I have two fail for my script.

1.publicAdvart.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#select_marka').change(function () {
            $.post(
                'modeli.php',
                {id: $('#select_marka').val()},
                function (res) {
                    $('#model').html(res);
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>

<select class="form-control" name="marka" id="select_marka">
<option></option>
<?php
$sel = "SELECT * FROM marka";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['marka']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

2.modeli.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != '') {
    $marka_id = $_POST['id'];
?>
<select id="select_marka" class="form-control">
<?php
    $selModel = "SELECT * FROM marka_model WHERE marka_id='$marka_id'";
    $queryModel = mysqli_query($conn, $selModel);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($queryModel)) {
?>

<option value="<?php echo $rows['model']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['model']; ?></option>

<?php
    }
?>
</select>

<?php
}
?>
```

Where is a problem? These two script  half work.

This is OK click "Opel" -> "meriva". https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5XZ.jpg

Next step 2 is a problem, i want "name" marka and "name" model.

Problem this is here.I don't get "marka - id", i want "name" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm1Yk.jpg

**Update:**

`step2.php`

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $marka = $_POST['marka']; 
        $model = $_POST['model'];

        $_SESSION['marka'] = $marka; 
        $_SESSION['model'] = $model; 
    }

?>

<div class="col-md-12 well advertTittle"> 
    <h4 class="well">
        <?php echo $_SESSION['marka'] . '&nbsp' . $_SESSION['model'] . '&nbsp' . stripslashes($_SESSION['modify']); ?> 
    </h4>
    <span><?php echo $_SESSION['price'] . ' лв.'; ?></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should post source code for `step 2` script

Comment: step2.php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$marka = $_POST['marka'];
$model = $_POST['model'];

$_SESSION['marka'] = $marka;
$_SESSION['model'] = $model;

}
 <div class="col-md-12 well advertTittle">
            <h4 class="well">
               ***<?php echo $_SESSION['marka'] . '&nbsp' . $_SESSION['model'] .     '&nbsp' . stripslashes($_SESSION['modify']); ?>***
            </h4>
            <span>               
                <?php echo $_SESSION['price'] . ' лв.'; ?>
            </span>
 </div>
The bold text is problem a picture up (41 and Undefined index: model.)

Comment: Under yours answer there is link (just below answer's tags), named `edit`. You can use it to edit yours answers (in future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to give the "name" attribute for yours "marka" select field:

```
<?php
    ...
?>
    <select id="select_marka" class="form-control"> // <- here
<?php
    $selModel = "SELECT * FROM marka_model WHERE marka_id='$marka_id'";
    ....
```

Should be something like this:

```
<?php
    ...
?>
    <select id="select_model" class="form-control" name="model"> // <- here!!! 
                                                                 // "id" attribute also should be changed
<?php
    $selModel = "SELECT * FROM marka_model WHERE marka_id='$marka_id'";
    ....
```

Also, yours step2.php should be like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['marka'] = $_POST['marka'];
    $_SESSION['model'] = $_POST['model'];
}

function validData($data) {
    return 
            isset($data['marka']) 
     && isset($data['model']) 
     && isset($data['price'])
     ;
}

if (validData($_SESSION)) {
    $marka_id = intval($_SESSION['marka']);
    $model_id = intval($_SESSION['model']);

    $marka = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM marka where id = $marka_id"));
    $model = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM marka_model WHERE id = $model_id"));

?>

<div class="col-md-12 well advertTittle">
    <h4 class="well">
        <?php echo $marka['name'] . '&nbsp' . $model['name'] . '&nbsp' . (isset($_SESSION['modify']) ? stripslashes($_SESSION['modify']) : ''); ?>***
    </h4>
    <span>               
        <?php echo $_SESSION['price'] . ' лв.'; ?>
    </span>
</div>

<?php } else { ?>

Not all fields filled.

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes my error, these "model" is OK i get "model", but  "marka" see "id", i want  Marka "name".Maby another script for get Marka "name"?

Comment: @СтилиянГеоргиев, look at updated answer. SQL queries may differ, as I don't know your's data tables structure